# Hewitt and Roberts map construction

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, graphs, tikz-datavisualization, mapping

does anyone know how to draw this map in latex ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful approach can be to include the "map" as a `node` in the `tikzpicture` and then trace it. The axes are drawn using the `loglogaxis` environment from `pgfplots`. The segment boundaries and labels are inserted with `\draw` and `\node` commands. Including the picture and tracing it makes it much easier to find the right controls for the Bezier curves.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{every node/.append style={font=\bfseries\Large}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Include the Hewitt and Roberts map as a node
%\node[] (A) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=20cm]{HR.png}};

% Draw the axes - both on the log scale
\begin{loglogaxis}[
at={(0.25,0.5)}, % this aligns the axes with the image
anchor=center,
xmin=1,
xmax=100000,
ymin=1,
ymax=10000,
width=17.2cm, % make the width the same as the imported image
height=13.5cm, % make the width the same as the imported image
enlargelimits=false,
ticklabel style={font=\huge\bfseries},
xlabel={liquid},
ylabel={gas},
ylabel style={rotate=-90}
]
\end{loglogaxis}

% Draw the boundaries
\draw[line width=3pt] (3.6,6.6) .. controls (1.9,5.6) and (1.9,4.4) .. (1.9,1.3);
\draw[line width=3pt] (-7.4,2.3) .. controls (-4.1,1.2) and (-3.5,1.2) .. (8,1.3);
\draw[line width=3pt] (3.9,1.3) .. controls (3.7,-2.7) and (4.4,-3.1) .. (6.5,-4.1);
\draw[line width=3pt] (3.9,0.5) .. controls (1.2,0.4) and (-1.3,-0.8) .. (-3.4,-4.5);

% Label the segments
\node at (-2.5,4) {Annular flow};
\node at (5,3.4) {Whispy annular};
\node at (-3.3,-0.9) {Churn flow};
\node at (1.2,-3.2) {Baby slug flow};
\node at (6.2,-0.6) {Bubble flow};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```